# Receiving content:/// URI's with a simple custom provider (ActivityNotFoundException)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, intentfilter, linkify

I'm writing a Twitter app, and have followed the Linkify guide from android-developers([http://android-deve..linkify-your-text.html](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html)) to make usernames (e.g. @brk3) clickable.

I have then created a content provider implementation to pick up intents that are fired when these are clicked.  My problem is that the intent doesn't seem to be finding my provider, so on clicking on one of the links I get the following exception:  (example is when clicking on username 'Arubin')

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5228): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.bourke.test/screenname/Arubin (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime( 5228):        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.j
ava:1512)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5228):        at      android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:138
4)
...
```

Here is the relavent piece of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:name="TestApplication"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

    <provider
       android:name="com.bourke.test.provider.TestProvider"
       android:authorities="com.bourke.test.provider" />

    <activity android:name="TestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType=
                "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.test.screenname" />;
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

And the provider:

```
package com.bourke.test.provider;

public class TestProvider extends ContentProvider {

    /* The root authority for this provider */
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.bourke.test.provider";

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "screenname";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + BASE_PATH);

    public static final int SCREEN_NAMES = 0;
    public static final int SCREEN_NAME = 1;

    private static final UriMatcher mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, SCREEN_NAMES);
        mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH+"/*", SCREEN_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "XXX: onCreate()");

        /* The provider was successfully loaded */
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,
            String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "XXX: getType()");

        switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SCREEN_NAMES:
                Log.d(TAG, "XXX1: SCREEN_NAMES");
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.test.screenname";

            case SCREEN_NAME:
                Log.d(TAG, "XXX2: SCREEN_NAME");
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.test.screenname";

            default:
                // any other kind of URL is illegal
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm not really concerned with using a database backend, though it may be useful to add in the near future.  Right now I just want enough to be able to pick up content://com.bourke.test/screenname/ style URI's, so my activity can then make Twitter API calls to show info on the appropriate user.

Any feedback or info on why this is crashing would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you sure,you don't miss to add Internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Thanks, but I have that there already to fetch the tweets, all of which is working. I just didn't paste the full file.

Comment: you calling `content://com.bourke.test/` content Uri but you definde it as `content://com.bourke.test.provider/`

Comment: @Selvin, that's it! It works!  Thanks so much, glad it was so simple :)  If you want to add your answer below I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From error we can assume that you calling `content://com.bourke.test/screenname/Arubin` but from your code looks like it should be `content://com.bourke.test.provider/screenname/Arubin` ... so you should add `.provider` when you calling this ContentUri or remove it from `public static final String AUTHORITY="...";`